# Neo4j Optimization Questions for Server Plug-in Queries

Tags: multithreading, performance, caching, cypher, neo4j

I'm trying to optimize a fuzzy search query.  It's fairly large, as it searches most properties in the database for a single word. I have some questions about some things I've been doing to  improve the search speed.

**Test Info**: I added about 10,000 nodes and I'm searching on about 40 properties.  My query times are about 3-30 seconds depending on the criteria.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE 
(n:Type__Exercise and ( n.description =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  or  n.name =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  ))  or  
(n:Type__Fault and ( n.description =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  or  n.name =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  ))

with n LIMIT 100
return count(n)
```

This is basically my query, but with a lot more OR clauses.  I also use parameters when sending the query to the execution engine.  I realize it's very expensive to use the regular expressions on every single property.  I'm hoping I can get good enough performance without doing exact matches up to a certain amount of data (This application will only have 1-10 users querying at a time).  **This is a possible interim effort we're investigating until the new label indexes support full text queries.**

**First of all, how do I tell if my query was cached?**  I make a call to my server plug-in via the curl command and the times I'm seeing are almost identical each time I pass the same criteria (The time is for the entire curl command to finish).  I'm using a single instance of the execution engine that was created by using the GraphDatabaseService that is passed in to the plug-in via a @Source parameter.  **How much of an improvement should I see if a query is cached?**

**Is there a query size where Neo4j doesn't bother caching the query?**

**How effective is the LIMIT clause at speeding up queries?**  I added one, but didn't see a great performance boost (for queries that do have results).  Does the execution engine stop once it finds enough nodes?

**My queries are ready-only, do I still have to wrap my calls with a transaction?**

I could split up my query so I only search one property at a time or say 4 properties at a time.  Then I could run the whole set of queries via the execution engine.  It seems like this would be better for caching, but **is there an added cost to running multiple small queries rather than one large one?**  **What if I kicked off 10 threads?  Would there be enough of a performance increase to make this worth while?**

**Is there a way to use parameters when using PROFILE in the Neo4j console?**  I've been trying to use this to see how many db hits I'm getting on my queries.

**How effective is the Neo4j browser for comparing times it takes to execute a query?**
Does caching happen here?

If I want to warm up Neo4j data for queries - can I run the exact queries I'm expecting?  Does the query need to return data, or will a count type query warm the cache?  As an alternative, should I just iterate over all the nodes?  I'd rather just pull in the nodes that are likely to be searched vs all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think for the time being you'd be better served using the fulltext-legacy indexing facilities, I recently wrote a blog post about it: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/

If you don't want to do that:

I would probably also rewrite your query to turn it around:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE 
   (n:Type__Exercise OR n:Type__Fault) AND 
   (n.description =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  OR  n.name =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  )
```

You can probably also benefit a bit more by having a secondary "search" field that is just the concatenation of your `description` and `name` fields. You probably also want to improve your regexp like adding a word boundary `\b` left and right.

Regarding your questions:

#### First of all, how do I tell if my query was cached?

Your query will be cached if you use parameters (for the regexps) there is a configurable query-caches size (defaulting to 100 queries)

#### Is there a query size where Neo4j doesn't bother caching the query?

Neo4j currently caches all queries that come in regardless of size

#### My queries are ready-only, do I still have to wrap my calls with a transaction?

Cypher will create its own transaction. In general read transactions are mandatory. For cypher you need outer transactions if you want multiple queries to participate in the same tx-scope.

#### is there an added cost to running multiple small queries rather than one large one? What if I kicked off 10 threads? Would there be enough of a performance increase to make this worth while?

It depends smaller queries are executed more quickly (if they touch less of the total dataset) but you have to combine their results in the client.

If they touch the same nodes you do double work.

For bigger queries you have to watch out when you span up cross products or exponential path explosions.

#### Regarding running smaller queries with many threads

Good question, it should be faster there are currently some bottlenecks that we're about to remove. Just try it out.

#### Is there a way to use parameters when using PROFILE in the Neo4j console?

You can use the shell variables for that, with `export name=value` and list them with `env`

e.g.

```
export name=Lisa

profile match (n:User {name:{name}}) return n;
```

#### How effective is the Neo4j browser for comparing times it takes to execute a query?

The browser measures the complete roundtrip with potentially more data loading, so it's timing is not very accurate.

#### Warmup

The exact queries would make sense
You don't have to return data, it is enough to `return count(*)` but you should access the properties you want to access to make sure they are loaded.

Comment: It doesn't seem like my queries are being cached.  I've kicked off the server plug-in with the same query multiple times and it runs the same number of seconds.  There could be a small difference I'm not seeing, but if my query takes 20 seconds, I feel like I should see at least a one second decrease in the execution time of the query if it's cached.  That's why I was wondering about the expected increase in performance for caching.  At the moment, I'm really trying to avoid using the legacy indexes, but if I can't get the queries to go fast enough, I may end up doing that.

Comment: About the warmup, I wasn't sure what you meant about accessing the properties.  The query I'm trying to cache only returns the count.  I create a second query to get the results after the user narrows down what they're after (which decreases the number of where clauses quite considerably).